# Python: Check if every file in a list exists in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

Im trying to make it so it will check from a list in a directory if every file name from the list exists or not if yes skip and if no create it but i keep runing in to the eror `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`  here is a code to just print the name of every file in a directory that works on the same princeble. (if i do only c:  for the directory it prints every file in the code directory)

```
import os


list_of_files = os.listdir('FILE_DIRECTORY_HERE')

print(list_of_files)
```

Comment: You need to replace ```\``` to ```\\``` or ```/```

Comment: i tried running the following code using python3 and it worked great:
`import os
list_of_files = os.listdir('/')
print(list_of_files)`

Comment: I didn't get it as there is no need to check if a file exists or not because `os.listdir('PATH')` returns files that exists only so there is no need to check and to fix that error just replace `C:\Users` with `C:\\Users` or before the string put `r` to declare it as a raw string `r'C:\Users\'` or just use simple slashes `'C:/Users/'`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this -

```
    import os
    list_of_files = os.listdir('C:\\temp')
    print(list_of_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is replacing the \ with /